# How to use use external js in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, type-conversion, typescript

I Generate the Angular JS code through the Typescript code. In one situation, I need to add external JS file to my typescript file and need to access the classes in the js file.

I add that js file like this.

```
/// <amd-dependency path="../../vendor/tweenMax.js" />
```

But still the typescript file can not identify the objects of that javascript file.

If someone knows the suitable way, please add your answer. (I'm using min. js file)

Answer (score 6):

You need a `.d.ts` file (TypeScript definition file) for any non-TypeScript packages.  The dependency references are only for TypeScript files (not plain js).

### https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

If a .d.ts file does not exist for your addin you can simply define an `interface` for it yourself (so that it thinks it exists).

It is purely for the strong-typing that it needs any definition, otherwise you can just cast your variable with `<any>` and call anything on it (whether it exists or not, just like normal JS) :)