# How to bundle (for browser) typescript external modules, generate d.ts and use in a client application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, commonjs, typescript1.5

I am working on a typescript framework to develop single page application on top of angularjs. As a development practice each class inside the framework has been implemented as separate file which in-turn becomes a typescript external module. The development IDE that I am working on is VS2015 with typescript 1.5.

square.ts

```
export class Square {
    constructor(color) {
    }
}
```

triangle.ts

```
export class Triangle {
    constructor(color: number) {
    }
}
```

rectangle.ts

```
export class Rectangle {
    constructor(color: number) {
    }
}
```

I would like to deploy the framework as a single js file instead of different external modules. So I have used the grunt + browserify + tsify combination to bundle the framework. For example all the above files have been transpiled and combined in to framework-production.js (a CommonJS module) as shown below.

```
var config = {
    client: {
        outDir: './',
        out: 'framework-production.js',
        options: {
            browserify: {
                entries: './framework.ts',
                extensions: ['.ts'],
                debug: true
            },
            tsify: {
                target: 'ES5',
                removeComments: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now I want to use this library(framework-production.js) to develop a typescript client application.

For that I need to develop a type definition file. The default type definition files generated by tsc are external modules. Instead of giving it as separate external module .d.ts file I would like to combine it into a single file.  let us call it framework-production.d.ts.

Question 1. Is there any tool available to combine d.ts files ?

Question 2. I have seen angular2 generating a combined d.ts files. Can any body help me to understand how exactly angular2 (not angular 1.x) achieves this?

I have manually combined / re-factored the d.ts files and generated framework.d.ts as shown below.

Question 3. Is this the right way to define a d.ts file?

```
declare module framework {
    class Rectangle {
        constructor(color: number);
    }

    class Triangle {
        constructor(color: number);
    }

    class Square {
        constructor(color: any);
    }
}

declare module "framework" {
    export = framework;
}
```

When I tried to use the framework-production.js and instantiate 'Square' class as given below;

```
<script src="framework-production.js"></script>
<script data-main="/app" src="/Scripts/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="framework-production.d.ts" />
new framework.Square(1);
```

it throws an error like;

```
Unhandled exception at line 20, column 1 in http://localhost:59182/app.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'framework' is undefined
```

Question 4. Could you please guide me to find out the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use use external js in typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135231/how-to-use-use-external-js-in-typescript)